# fadeIn background image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a working code that changes my document background image when links in my navbar are clicked. The background image changes instantly with no animation. How could I make the new background image fadeIn(); ?

js

```
$('.navigation a').click(function() {
    currentBg = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '') +'.jpg';
    $('.background').css({'background-image':'url(images/skins/'+currentBg+')'});
});
```

Comment: I would like to know this to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can, the only way (that I know of) would be to have a block element (div for example) which has the background and that appears behind the rest of your content (positioned absolutely) and fade that in instead of switching backgrounds.

Comment: Well, technically, there's another option: get that image, draw on canvas with some alpha, read back as data/url and set background... but this is even more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate the background image changing its opacity.

May be you can have a image with required opacity at different sections and then animate the background position so that it gives a `fadeIn` behavior.

Take a look at this [link](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/animated-background-image-with-jquery) it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possiblity to fade the background image, you have to create a container and set its background image to let it fade in and fade out.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before by floating a foreground image on a separate div on top of the background image you'd like to 'fade' in and then creating a jquery fade-out effect on the foreground image.

You can use a similar trick to set solid text on a semi-transparent "background".

http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with int0x90.

What you can do is this:

1. Stack your images in a div, style position absolute, style of each image position absolute
2. set an id for the div
3. add a class active, with a z-index of 10
4. set all inactive images in div z-index to 0
5. you can use the z-index to pull the image with the highest z-index to the top of the stack
6. add class active to the on-click of nav bar link and remove this class from the previous on click so that the image's z-index is set back to 0 and not overridden.
7. in jquery, you may now be able to use opacity change and the speed of the change

hope this helps get you started!

Answer (score 0):

As many others already said, it's impossible unless you use a block element as background.
But if you only want an animation, you could have a .gif as background then when it's animation has finished replace it with the real Image so the .gif doesn't iterate itself